# Insert a customer record, then insert multiple records associated, not working

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

I tried to come up with a title that is as close to the issue I am having as possible.

We have a pharmaceutical store and we are trying to give our customers the ability to refill their prescription drugs online.

Our presumption is that a customer could have more than one prescriptions they would like to refill at same time.

So, our design is broken down into two parts.

At top of page, a user is required to provide three pieces of personal information (lastname, email address,phone number).

Then at the bottom of the page is a textbox that is dynamically generated.

In other words, a user enters first prescription refill and if there is another prescription the user would like to refill, the user clicks the **Add Another Refill** button to provide another prescription number.

The user can provide a maxmimum of 6 prescription refills.

This works fine.

The issue we have is adding this information to the database.

The code provided below adds customer's personal information into Customer table but adding the presicrions information to the Prescriptions table is not storing the information.

Any ideas what i am doing wrong?
Thanks in advance

```
Protected Sub btnSave_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim s As String
    Dim sql As String
    Dim connStr As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;data source=" & Server.MapPath("App_Data\GCP.mdb")
    Try
        SetRowData()
        Dim table As DataTable = TryCast(ViewState("CurrentTable"), DataTable)

        If table IsNot Nothing Then

            s = "INSERT INTO Customer(Lastname, Email_Address, Phone) Values (?, ?, ?)"
            sql = "Select Max(custId) From Customer"
            'Response.Write(s)
            'Response.End()
            Dim con As New OleDbConnection(connStr)
            Dim cmd1 As New OleDbCommand(s, con)
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("", txtlName.Text)
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("", txtemail.Text)
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("", txtphone.Text)
            con.Open()
            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cmd1.CommandText = sql
            ID = cmd1.ExecuteScalar()

            For Each row As DataRow In table.Rows
                Dim txRefill As String = TryCast(row.ItemArray(1), String)

                If txRefill IsNot Nothing Then

                    Try
                        s = "INSERT INTO Employee_Roster(refillNumber, custId) VALUES "
                        s += "('" & txRefill & "', " & ID & ")"
                        'Response.Write(s)
                        'Response.End()
                        'Dim connStr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("allstringconstrng").ConnectionString
                        Dim conn As New OleDbConnection(connStr)
                        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(s, conn)
                        conn.Open()
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                        conn.Close()


                        'Display some feedback to the user to let them know it was processed
                        lblResult.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green
                        lblResult.Text = "Record successfully saved!"

                        'Clear the form
                        txRefill = ""
                    Catch

                        'If the message failed at some point, let the user know
                        lblResult.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
                        lblResult.Text = "Your record failed to save, please try again."

                    End Try

                End If
            Next
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw New Exception(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: What exception does it throw? In the catch block assign the exception value to the lblResult.Text so you know what exception it throws.

Comment: I got it worked out just now.

It was pointing to the wrong table.

Thanks for trying to hel @AdarshShah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code was pointing to the wrong table.

I got it working after fixing that problem.

Employee_Roster is the wrong table.